# I have a python file with multiple exception for each block , I need to utest for the same . Is there any approach to cover all exceptions at one go?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Sample python file for which utest is to be written:

```py
try:

    code

except Exception as e:
    print



try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print

try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print

try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print

try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print

try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print
    

try:

    code

except Exception as e:

    print
```

Comment: The next time please make sure you post your code properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```py
try:
    foo()
except (SomeException, OtherException, AnotherException) as exp:
    ...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions